Why does Ubuntu 24.04 automatically create a user called Ubuntu? Can I remove it without any problems?
When I installed Ubuntu 24.04, I noticed a folder named Ubuntu in the /home directory. Is this an automatically created user account by Ubuntu? Can I safely remove it without any issues?

Sure, as long as you created another user to log in as!

If you are talking about VPSes and prebuilt images, that's why 'ubuntu' exists so you have a login to use to start setting up and using the system.  The standard ISOs never set up the user.

If starting from the Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server iso files, only the live session (booted from the installation media) has a default 'Ubuntu' user name. When installing you will have the option to select a user name. If starting from a compressed image of a preinstalled system, Ubuntu comes with a default 'ubuntu' user name. Please tell us details about how you created your system and we can give you detailed advice.

Installing ubuntu doesn't necessarily create a folder /home/ubuntu unless you entered ubuntu as the primary system ID when first installing ubuntu.  You can verify this by using the command whoami at the main terminal once the system boots up.
If in fact, that's what you've done, I'd recommend not attempting to delete the /home/ubuntu folder.
